# Magento 2.3 re-index failing for sales rule index

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, reindex

When I trying to re-index salesrule_rule index, It gives me bellow error and the sales rule grid is not loading in magento admin. Please advice.

`Item (Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Interceptor) with the same ID "165" already exists.`

Attached is the MySQL result when I run query to see all the rules having 165 as rule_id

[image]

Comment: did you migrate your data? run the following in your phpmyadmin select * from salesrule where rule_id = 165; and if you can update the above question with the results then i can give you a more accurate solution

Comment: Hi @DavaGordon, highly appreciate your prompt reply. I updated the question with information you requested.

Comment: DavaGordon, I didn't migrate any data recently.

Comment: row 443 and 477 look like they could possible be the issue you are having as they have the same date ranges

Comment: Dava Gordon, I removed above rules one by one and had no luck. I then removed all the rules with rule_id=165. Then issue fixed :) needed rules re-created. Thanks a lot for guidance

Comment: glad it helped id recommend always making rules unique so you can easily track down issues such as this.